# Antd Form Item Dynamic Fields mixed with fields that apply to all sub items

Tags: reactjs, antd

So for a template I was using this link below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-uhu2v

I have more fields and labels and such but the basic premise is the same.

So basically what I was hoping someone could help me figure out is:
I have some forms on top that I want to apply to every item made, and then below you create as many items as you want. Right now if you go of the code example, it creates an object array of "inclusions" that pass in all the info made in the dynamic fields.

Is there a way for me to take the fields on top, and push them into all the dynamic items?

Like have date created at the top as one field. Then you make like 10 items. Then each item will have that date with the other data.

Right now I create one master item, that has an array of objects inside it. Instead I want to create an array of objects, with all the information.